# How to make bash command echo lines green

Tags: linux, bash, terminal-color

I have a bash script with command echo turned on (set -x).  I want the echo lines to be printed in green text, but the output of the actual commands to be in whatever the default color is.  I can use $PS4 to get the green, but I don't see a way to turn it of after each echo, so the result is that all output becomes green.

Comment: Instead of using ANSI control characters, you might check if your terminal emulator can automatically highlight lines that match a specific regular expression (and set `PS4` so that the desired lines can be matched uniquely.)

Comment: what do you mean lines to be printed ?

Comment: @JID, when you put `set -x` in a script, bash prints to the terminal every command before it executes it.  Additionally, various commands may have some output which they also print to the terminal.  I want to distinguish between the two by color.

Comment: @chepner, interesting idea, but I'm hoping to get a portable solution that will work across different terminal emulators.

Comment: I don't know that you can do this directly. You can do this with post-processing easily enough though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<> >(sed -e "s/.*/\o033[0;32m&\o033[0m/")
BASH_XTRACEFD=3
set -x
...
```

(requires bash 4.1, I believe; use awk or perl or bash builtins instead of sed if you prefer)

Comment: Brilliant! (Though I ended up using sed rather than perl.)

Comment: @Ari: what did it look like with sed?

Comment: `exec 3<> >(sed -e "s/.*/\o033[0;32m&\o033[0m/")`

Comment: The perl version actually had a small problem if one of the script's commands failed, causing the script to exit.  In that case the last line printed by the script wasn't terminated by a newline, and the prompt appeared at the line's end rather than in a new line.  The sed version didn't have this problem, and I didn't bother trying to figure out what causes it with perl.